# Populating a Listview from ListBox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview

Good morning

This is frustrating the life out of me and I know it's going to be simple. I moved some code from a `Listbox` to a `Listview` to get columns and have set my `Listview` to 'Details' and set up two columns (`PartID` and `PartDesc`). All looks good in the designer.

I run the code below and get no columns and no data in the `Listview`. Any ideas. (I purely set the strings to variable and use those so I can see the data being passed)

```
For Each row As DataRow In SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows
    Dim PartID As String = row.Item(0).ToString
    Dim PartDesc As String = row.Item(1).ToString
    With lvUsedOn
        .Items.Add(PartID)
        .Items(lvUsedOn.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(PartDesc)
    End With
Next
```

Comment: Not sure why my title got edited? I am just trying to populate a Listview by iterating through the rows of a SQL data table and finding it really tough. The Listbox is now not relevant. I was just giving context as to why I was moving to Listview. Still no answers though

Comment: I'm not having an issue using your posted code.  Have you debugged your code and see that your items are getting added to your lvUsedOn or that your code isn't throwing an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
lvUsedOn.Items.Add(New ListViewItem({PartID, PartDesc}))
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I'm now beginning to think I have an issue elsewhere. I have tried various code to add items to a listview, including yours and they all seem to work in a simple fashion. In design view I can see the two columns I have set up and it is in 'Details' view, but when running the code I get no data or indeed no defined columns or headings? Tried adding a fresh Listview but still no go I'm afraid. Could there be any other properties I must set to do this. (BTW: No image list set in case that matters?)

Comment: Josh Thanks for trying to help. I've had a duh moment. For some reason I was invoking a method I'd written that was clearing them! Sorry to waste peoples time but guess we all have these moments? (at least I hope others do?)